# UHD+ Touchscreen for Content Creation

Tags: monitors, displays, 4k, touchscreen

For arguments sake there is no upper bound on my budget, but the lower the better, clearly.

I am looking for a touchscreen display of 30 inches or greater that has a resolution of 3840 x 2160 or greater.

It will be for content creation and other similar usage.